# What happen when I feed lstm as multidimension array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I create lstm model from tensorflow like this

```
model.add(LSTM(6, input_shape=(1, 6), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(3))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam' )
model.fit(X_train_t, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=3, verbose=1)
```

The value of X_train_t is

```
[[ 0.46412556  0.24775785  0.20179372  0.23430493  0.16704036  0.24215247]
 [ 0.          0.46412556  0.24775785  0.20179372  0.23430493  0.16704036]
 [ 0.15022422  0.          0.46412556  0.24775785  0.20179372  0.23430493]
 [ 0.2690583   0.15022422  0.          0.46412556  0.24775785  0.20179372]
 [ 0.2690583   0.2690583   0.15022422  0.          0.46412556  0.24775785]
 [ 0.24775785  0.2690583   0.2690583   0.15022422  0.          0.46412556]
 [ 0.21076233  0.24775785  0.2690583   0.2690583   0.15022422  0.        ]
...
```

It have no error but I don't understand . LSTM get input is time series and loop in one node.

[image]

Why it have no error when I put multidimension array I think correct input should be like this. How lstm get input ?

```
[[ 0.24215247]
 [ 0.16704036]
 [ 0.23430493]
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LSTM takes as input vectors, not numbers. Your specified as input shape:

```
input_shape=(1, 6)
```

So 6-dim vectors, this is exactly what you are feeding in with every time step:

```
[ 0.46412556  0.24775785  0.20179372  0.23430493  0.16704036  0.24215247]
```

So a input sequence with 3 time steps would than look like this:

```
[[ 0.46412556  0.24775785  0.20179372  0.23430493  0.16704036  0.24215247]
 [ 0.          0.46412556  0.24775785  0.20179372  0.23430493  0.16704036]
 [ 0.15022422  0.          0.46412556  0.24775785  0.20179372  0.23430493]]
```

(3 vectors with each 6 dimensions)